# API_UNAVAILABLE Google API client

Tags: android, google-plus

Couldn't connect to Google API client: `ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null}`

I am trying to implement the basic g+ login in my app and I have followed the steps exactly like in [Drive API for Android Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/get-started).

Has anyone seen this error before?

When I click on the signin button I get the prompt to select my google account. Once I select the account nothing happens in my app.

The logs are below:

```
E/MDM     (32664): [33508] b.run: Couldn't connect to Google API client: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null}
I/LoadedApk(32664): getClassLoader :dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar", zip file "/system/framework/com.android.media.remotedisplay.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.google.android.gms-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.google.android.gms-2/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]]
I/SurfaceFlinger( 3100): id=2396 Removed SurfaceView (-2/9)
D/LocationInitializer(29281): Restart initialization of location
W/ActivityManager( 3499): userId = 0, bbcId = -10000
W/ActivityManager( 3499): NORMAL SET : dst_category = 701, src_allowCategory = 0,701-1023
```

Comment: Hope my experience may help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/34089712/755313

Answer (score 4):

As per Google docs for [API_UNAVAILABLE](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult.html#API_UNAVAILABLE):

> One of the API components you attempted to connect to is not available. The API will not work on this device, and updating Google Play services will not likely solve the problem. Using the API on the device should be avoided.

Also check if you have put the correct settings and keys in the [manifest](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/java-client#set_mime_types_in_the_app_manifest).
Try on different device if possible. If you post the code how you are creating the client, device type/os etc, it might have narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Same happened here.I thought it was activated, but, as i did, you probably haven't activated Google+ Api on the Google Api Console.

- Login here: https://console.developers.google.com/project?authuser=0
- Choose your project
- Find "APIs and Auth" on the left
- Click on API
- On this list, you'll see many APIs available.

Click on the APIs you want and you'll find a button "activate" on the top.

Wait a few minutes, close your app and try again. It will probably work.

Comment: i am not using any API. i am doing sample app on material design