# Google Sign-In Error - API_UNAVAILABLE requesting Gmail scope on a Gmail account

Tags: gmail-api, google-signin

My app works for 99% of users but one got this error:

```
API_UNAVAILABLE
```

When using Google Sign in on their @gmail.com account.

I know it is possible in G-Suite for an admin to disable APIs. But is it even possible to disable the gmail API on a gmail account?

Comment: Have you seen these related links: [SO 30314765](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30314765/), [SO 30650231](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30650231/couldnt-connect-to-google-api-client/34089712#34089712), [Constant: API_UNAVAILABLE](https://developers.google.cn/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult#API_UNAVAILABLE)

Comment: @Jacque - yes thanks I have seen those. The answers there are all configuration-related which would return this error consistently for any account. However I am only getting this error for some accounts. The question is why are some accounts failing and not others.