# Google map api key android error

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a problem when I use GoogleMap API, I think my app don't find my api_key (see the log) whereas I write it in code. MapView is opened during few second and crash. In Google API site, I enable Geocoding api, google place for android, google maps for android.

My **Manifest.xml**:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="fr.mapeche.testnav1" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <!-- The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_prises"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".view.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" >

        <!-- configChanges Permet de ne pas perdre les données lors de la rotation d'écran -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" >
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />//The wright API_KEY
</application>
```

A part of **log** :

```
06-16 15:30:00.944  10741-10852/? E/MDM﹕ [24597] b.run: Couldn't connect to Google API client: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null}
06-16 15:30:00.986  10741-10855/? E/MDM﹕ [24598] b.run: Couldn't connect to Google API client: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null}
06-16 15:30:01.077  736-840/? E/WifiStateMachine﹕ WifiStateMachine CMD_START_SCAN source 10007 txSuccessRate=0,00 rxSuccessRate=0,00 targetRoamBSSID=00:23:69:93:39:66 RSSI=-69
06-16 15:30:01.105  736-840/? E/WifiStateMachine﹕ WifiStateMachine CMD_START_SCAN source 10007 txSuccessRate=0,00 rxSuccessRate=0,00 targetRoamBSSID=00:23:69:93:39:66 RSSI=-69
06-16 15:30:02.405  9811-9811/fr.mapeche.testnav1 E/DatabaseHelper﹕     SELECT * FROM fishing ORDER BY fishing_date DESC
06-16 15:30:07.538  11045-11154/? E/SQLiteLog﹕ (283) recovered 12 frames from WAL file /data/data/com.google.android.gms/databases/playlog.db-wal
06-16 15:30:09.162  11212-11212/? E/GmsWearableLS﹕ GoogleApiClient connection failed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null}
06-16 15:30:09.177  11212-11296/? E/MDM﹕ [24645] b.run: Couldn't connect to Google API client: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null}
06-16 15:30:09.268  11212-11308/? E/MDM﹕ [24649] b.run: Couldn't connect to Google API client: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null}
```

Comment: Your problems doesn't seem the API bey, but the connection to the service. Check your Internet connection or your Google Project Center for the correct permissions

Comment: I already check internet connection using permission in manifest, it-is the good way ?

Comment: You should check if your device has Internet, eg using the browser

Comment: Of course my device has internet

Comment: OK, then it will be ahother thing

Comment: possible duplicate of [API\_UNAVAILABLE Google API client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30314765/api-unavailable-google-api-client)

Comment: I have already see this post and I try issues, but I have another problem

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and I found the connection was the problem. You have to create two credentials(one for debug and another one for release versions) and put them to the suitable google maps api xml files then the API wouldn't be your problem. You have to check the connection or other things.