# google api client could not connect LocationService.API is unavailable

Tags: android, google-api-client, location-services

Im trying to make a service that tracks the phone with the google fused location api but the GoogleApiClient can't connect to LocationService.API
This is the message i get when i search in the console for google api client
    `Couldn't connect to Google API client: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null}`

The GoogleApiClient code i used to connect is this

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
        .build();
```

just like every tutorial on the internet tells me to use.

Do anyone know why this doesn't work for me?
I can get the gps position from the android api.

Comment: Are you making one request to connect? Or multiple? You may have an outdated version of Google Play Services. Also, read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30314765/api-unavailable-google-api-client) thread

Comment: None, Maybe thats why? I just added it to the onCreate to see if that works. Thank you for noticing that

Comment: Yes that is why! Thank you<3 I have been trying to figure this out for over 4 hours...

Comment: Excellent! That is great news.

Answer (score 0):

From discussion, it sounds like you are not making multiple connection requests (if necessary) to the api client. Also, try adding the following permissions to the manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input but it turns out I completly forgot to connect the mGoogleApiClient with .connect() Now it records the rute as it is supposed to do.

Comment: Excellent! That happens brotha